# Cannot open shapefile

Tags: shapefile, carto, geojson, coordinate-system

I'm trying to open [this shapefile](http://www.vivienda.gob.ar/unqui/zip/0001cabay24partidos.zip) with [CartoDB](http://cartodb.com/) or http://geojson.io, but I keep getting different kind of errors.

I can open it with QGIS, but then I tried exporting it to GeoJSON, KML, ESRI shapefile, and others, and I always get lots of records but nothing on the map.

I'd like to just convert it to GeoJSON so that I can open it with any tool.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to assign the CRS `EPSG:22195 Campo Inchauspe/Argentina 5`, which makes it fit to Buenos Aires streets. You can do that with ARCGIS, QGIS or GDAL.

Or create a file named RGBA01P.prj with this content:

```
PROJCS["Campo_Inchauspe_Argentina_5",GEOGCS["GCS_Campo Inchauspe",DATUM["D_Campo_Inchauspe",SPHEROID["International_1924",6378388,297]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",-90],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-60],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",5500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

Once the .prj file is written, you can reproject to any other CRS and format.

Answer (score 2):

I opened it in ArcGIS and I noticed it wasn't projected. Therefore, you can see the attribute information, but geojson, or any other format (esri shape or kml) can't place it on the Earth. Try projecting it.